# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric while working with CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a `CASE` statement to return result based on given condition. This is only a select statement all the columns are of `nvarchar` data type, and I don't know why I get an error

> Error converting nvarchar to numeric

because I am not using any int values in the query.

Could you please help me?

```
CASE 
   WHEN COALESCE(gu.mrpsafetystatus, hmdr.MRP) = 'MRP Unsafe' THEN 'MRP_UNSAFE'
   WHEN COALESCE(gu.mrpsafetystatus, hmdr.MRP) = 'Unspecified' THEN 'UNSPECIFIED'
   WHEN COALESCE(gu.mrpsafetystatus, hmdr.MRP) = 'MRP Compatible' THEN  'MRP_COMPATIBLE'
   WHEN COALESCE(gu.mrpsafetystatus, hmdr.MRP) = 'MR_COMPATIBLE' THEN 'MRP_COMPATIBLE'
   WHEN COALESCE(gu.mrpsafetystatus, hmdr.MRP) = 'Labeling does not contain MRP Safety Information' THEN 'UNSPECIFIED'
END AS column1
```

I observed the issue occurs from the condition

```
WHEN COALESCE(gu.mrpsafetystatus, hmdr.MRP) = 'Labeling does not contain MRP Safety Information' THEN 'UNSPECIFIED'
```

Comment: Is datatype of MRP nvarchar?

Comment: yes its nvarchar(200)

Comment: @user13949321 Your code must be working as I think, please provide the `gu` and `hmdr` table structure and sample input. And please update your question with those information to check further. :)

Comment: We would like to believe you - but there is little point to debugging a code fragment. Don't assume - just post the complete query. DDL would also be useful. Sometimes the error is in place that you don't expect.

Comment: Is `gu.mrpsafetystatus` NVARCHAR datatype ?

Comment: I agree @SMor but it was more than 2000 lines of query.so i cant post everything.

Comment: HI @VenkataramanR yes  the column mrpsafetystatus is with datatype nvarchar(2000)

Comment: When I try, I am not getting any error: `DECLARE @table table(mrpsafetystatus NVARCHAR(2000), MRP NVARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO @table values(N'Test',N'Test');

SELECT CASE
when Coalesce(mrpsafetystatus ,MRP)= 'Labeling does not contain MRP Safety Information' then 'UNSPECIFIED'
END 
FROM @table`. I think may be you are facing error in another place

Comment: when i comment that particular line the rest of the query was executing fine.

Comment: I think both the Columns within the COALESCE(gu.mrpsafetystatus, hmdr.MRP) Statement has different Data Type - Might be one in NVARCHAR Data type and the Another One in INT  Data type. So it may also a reason for this Issue. Plz Check from your Side -- @user13949321

Comment: More than 2000 lines - then there is almost a guarantee that your error lies somewhere else if the only columns shown that are used in some comparison are, as you claim, the same datatype. And if what you claim is true, then why are you NOT using unicode literals?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have written could only generate a type conversion error if at least one of `gu.mrpsafetystatus` and `hmdr.MRP` are numbers and not strings.

What happens in this case is a type conversion in one of two places:

- If one of them is a number and the other a string, then a string that does not convert correctly would generate the error.
- If one or both of them are numbers or can be converted safely to numbers, then the string constant for the comparison is causing the error.

A simply way to avoid this particular error is to convert the values to strings.  This is safe for numbers, so you can use something like this:

```
COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), gu.mrpsafetystatus), CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), hmdr.MRP))
```

That said, the error would seem to be a *logic* problem.  You are clearly expecting the values to be strings.  If either is a number, you are probably using the wrong column.

I will also add that the most common situation where a type conversion occurs in a `case` expression is because the `THEN`/`ELSE` clauses have incompatible types.  In this case, though, all appear to be strings.